# How to get image to be placed on the left side of text input?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have been trying to fit an image inside of the text input to the left, i have tried using float, i have tried making it a div and wrapping it, i have tried making the background image to the image, and it either breaks it or doesn't make an difference. Not sure what to do.

```css
body {
  background-color: #141c2f;
}

.search {
  background-color: #1d2c4c;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.infoBox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/css/app.css">
  <title>Github User Search App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="infoBox">
    <input class="search" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where is the image element that you tried to add?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to put the image above input to the left (if you just want them side by side, use `display: flex` in class `.infoBox`). So You can use `:before` to get that, add this code to your:

```
.infoBox {
    position: relative;
}
.infoBox:before {
    content: '';
    background: url('your image url') center center no-repeat;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
.search {
    padding-left: 65px;
}
```

All attributes can be modify to your liking.